# Summing the same column twice under different criteria from the same table month by month

Tags: sql

Ive done this sql but i need some help changing it

```
select id, (select sum(col1) from t1) as totalcol1, 
(select sum(col1) from t1 where id = 7) as total_for_id from t1
group by id
```

So basically i want to sum up col1 for every id and also sum up col1 for where id=7, all from the same table t1. i want to be able to expand this query out by create date and month by month and every way i try i keep either getting a too many values error or the sub query retrieves more than one row of values. so something like

```
select (select to_char(view_date,'Mon-YY') from t1 group by to_char(view_date,'Mon-YY'))
as month, id, (select sum(col1) from t1 where view_date between '30-nov-2013' and '01-dec-
2013') as totalcol1, (select sum(col1) from t1 where id = 7 and view_date between '30-nov-2013' and '01-dec-2013')
as total_for_id from t1
group by id
```

i realise this is poor, any solutions would be appreciated

right i may as well show its a the output i want

```
month --|- id --|--- sum(col1 where id = 7) --|---sum(col1)

nov-13  ---  7   --------------100---------------   1000

dec-13  ---  7  -------------- 200  --------------  1500
```

Comment: Your question is tagged both [tag:mysql] (a cross-platform, open-source RDBMS, now owned by Oracle) and [tag:sql-server] (a proprietary, closed-source RDBMS from Microsoft). Which are you using?

Comment: What RDBMS is it for? Does it support analytic functions?

Comment: Please post the desired format of the result, since it's absolutely unclear how you envision it.  You `GROUP BY id` will show the result for `id=7` on its row.

Comment: i want id = 7 on the row

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
select to_char(view_date, 'Mon-YY'), 7 as id,
       sum(col1) as totalcol1, 
       sum(case when id = 7 then col1 else 0 end) as total_for_id7
from t1
group by to_char(view_date, 'Mon-YY')
order by min(view_date);
```

I added the `order by` so the results would be in date order.  Have you considered using a format for dates like `'YYYY-MM'` that can also be used for sorting?

Comment: Well... If this is indeed what OP wants (and it may as well be the case), you're a mind reader.

Comment: wont include an id column though, want a row saying id=7

Comment: @bram91 . . . If you are summarizing by month, which `id` do you want?

Comment: i want one column to sum by id=7 and the other to sum by all ids but i want id=7 on both rows if it was for november and december say

Answer (score 1):

CASE is your friend. Use this all the time for reports, but it is pretty slow.

```
Select sum(col1) as Total, 
  sum(Case When id=7 Then col1 Else 0 End) as TotalId7,
  ...
From t1
```

Comment: i ideally want the id displayed on the row though so it would mean adding a where id = 7 which would screw up the sum(col1)